# Using ReactJS together with TypeScript in Visual Studio, MVC5 project

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a minimal working expample for using `ReactJS` together with `TypeScript` in Visual Studio 2015.

After following the most tutorials found nothing of them is working and non of them is targeting my needs exactly.

I want to write components as `.tsx` files to have type-safety and reuse existing classes, definitions, interfaces already written.

These should be converted into `.jsx` to enable usage as `React.render(<SomeComponent />, document.getElementById("content"))` inside cshtml.

Depending on my project-config I either get the error that require is not a function or unexpected toke < in SomeCompnent.tsx.

Later on it should also be possible to use server-side rendering from ReactJS.NET to improve performance/user-experience.

Are there any tutorial I am missing which describe how to use TypeScript, ReactJS, Visual Studio 2015, MVC5 from scratch?

These are the settings from the `TypeScript Build` tab of my project's properties:

```
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptJSXEmit>React</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptOutFile />
<TypeScriptOutDir />
<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptMapRoot />
<TypeScriptSourceRoot />
```

This is the content of my `SomeComponent.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface IProps {
    name:string
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<IProps, undefined> {
    render() {
        return <div>Say hello to {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
}

export function render(componentName:string, mountNode: HTMLElement) {
    ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent name={componentName} />, mountNode);
}
```

My App.ts:

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {render} from "./Components/SomeComponent";

render("some name", document.getElementById("content"));
```

which gets converted to App.js:

```
"use strict";
var SomeComponent_1 = require("./Components/SomeComponent");
SomeComponent_1.render("some name", document.getElementById("content"));
//# sourceMappingURL=App.js.map
```

The Index.cshtml is simply:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/App.js"></script>
</body>
```

Last but not least package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactjstest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "15.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.23"
  }
}
```

Comment: `.tsx` files which are compiled into `.js` files can be used with `React.render` as well, there's no need to compile them into `.jsx`, but that's possible. Please include your `tsconfig.json` and code where you import.

Comment: @NitzanTomer when compiling into `.js` I end up with the error telling me that `require` is not a function.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I don't have a tsconfig.json as the settings are stored in the `.csproj` file. Will add the parts to my question

Answer (score 0):

This setup works (I'm not using VS, but you can get the idea):

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

(you can choose a different module system)

page.ts

```
import { render } from "./main";
render("how are you?", document.getElementById("content"));
```

main.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Prompt } from "./prompt";

class HelloWorld extends React.Component<{ prompt: string }, void> {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello world><Prompt value={ this.props.prompt } /></div>;
    }
}

export function render(prompt: string, mount: HTMLElement) {
    ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld prompt={ prompt }/>, mount);
}
```

prompt.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export class Prompt extends React.Component<{ value: string }, void> {
    render() {
        return <span>{ this.props.value }</span>;
    }
}
```

You need to make sure you have the react packages:

```
npm install --save react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Comment: What is the difference between using `import React = require("react")` and `import * as React from "react"`?

Comment: The `import * as X from Y` is the new `es6` form. The `import X = require(Y)` is [used when the lib exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) using `export =`. In this case you can use both, but I recommend using the first (`import * ...`).

Comment: I now get the error `require is not defined`. I've updated my question by adding the file-content of the files in question as I don't see what I am missing. The error is thrown at line `import {render} from "./Components/SomeComponent";`

Comment: You are using `<TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>` for compiling, but are you loading your js files using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: Currently I trying to go with webpack. But this  ends up in `React is not defined`.

Comment: Well, that's a completely different question. And looks like SO has quite a few threads regarding "webpack React is not defined"